# ¿Como hacer que se abra la PlayStore si una app no esta instalada?

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de que el código detecte si una app esta instalada en el telefono y si lo esta entonces que se abra, si no lo esta entonces abrir la **PlayStore** o mas bien que busque la app para que se descargue.

```
public void open8 (View view){

    if(InstaladaAplicacion("com.example.speedometer", getApplicationContext())){

    }else{
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/");
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(i);

    }

    String PackageName = "com.example.speedometer";
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.speedometer");

    if(intent == null) {

    }
    startActivity(intent);

}

private boolean InstaladaAplicacion(String s, Context applicationContext) {
    return false;
}
```

Intenté con esto para ver si funciona y creo que si detecta que la app esta instalada pero no estoy seguro del todo, entonces al tenerla instalada la abre, borré la app para probar si abre la PlayStore y resulta que no(La app se detiene).

Answer (score 6):

El método para detectar si la aplicación se encuentra instalada en el dispositivo a partir de su [packagename](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html), sería:

```
public static boolean instaladaAplicacion(String packagename, Context context) {
    boolean response = false;
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        response = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i("Android", "NNFE aplicación no instalada: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}
```

Por lo tanto, primeramente buscas si la aplicación definida por su  [packagename](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html), se encuentra instalada. Si se encuentra instalada la abre en el dispositivo.

Si no se encuentra instalada abre la aplicación en Google Playstore  para que el usuario la instalé, en este caso necesitas formar la url con el protocolo `market://`.

Este sería el código:

```
    String packageName = "com.example.speedometer";
    String MARKET_SQUEME = "market://details?id=";

    //Verifica si la aplicación se encuentra instalada.
    if(instaladaAplicacion(packageName, getApplicationContext())){
        Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);            
        //Abre aplicación.
        startActivity(i); 
    }else{ //No se encuentra instalada.
        //Abre aplicación en  Playstore
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(MARKET_SQUEME + packageName)));
    }
```

Comment: Todo el codigo esta perfecto pero me da un error en donde dice: InstaladaAplicacion , me dice que para resolverlo hay que agregar un método, lo agrego y despues hay que ponerle return true; para que se ejecute y solo se ejecuta If y si pongo return false; se ejecuta Else.

Comment: Hola Alejandro, El método InstaladaAplicacion es el que esta al inicio de la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias! jejeje no habia colocado el método correcto.

Answer (score 1):

Como complemento a la respuesta de @Jorgesys

Me he encontrado que no siempre los enlaces `market://details?id=:` abren la app Google play correctamente, por ejemplo en mi Moto G funciona, pero en mi Acer Liquid z200 no funciona.

Suelo usar más `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=` que si la app google play está instalada se muestra para abrirla con ella sino con el navegador.

Si se quiere contemplar diferentes escenarios si el usuario tiene instalada la Google Play o bien como alternativa abre el navegador.

```
private String getGooglePlayStoreUrl(){
    String id = activity.getApplicationInfo().packageName; // current google play is   using package name as id

    PackageManager packageManager = activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + id);
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(marketUri);
    if (marketIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null)
      return "market://details?id=" + id;
    else
      return "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + id;
 }
```

Comment: Hola Webserveis, esto que comentas no lo había experimentado,  trabajando con dispositivos desde el [dispositivo de desarrollo G1](http://www.gsmarena.com/t_mobile_g1-2533.php), no pude experimentar lo que mencionas, pero nunca he trabajado con un "Acer Liquid z200", el  esquema market:// funcionaba si tenias la aplicación "market" y "Play store", pero claro, esto si esta instalada en el dispositivo, no sería esto? o aún instalada la aplicación no funcionaba con market:// ?

Comment: exacto no todos los dispositivos vienen con el market preisntalado, en cambio si se usa la play.google. pues si no hay market instalado se abre el navegador o bien la app "play store"