# App no funciona en android 5.0, pero si en android 7.0

Tags: java, android, eclipse

soy novato en programación. Estoy ejecutando una app que detecte si una app está instalada y sino que abra el play store; Encontré este código [¿Como hacer que se abra la PlayStore si una app no esta instalada?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103223/como-hacer-que-se-abra-la-playstore-si-una-app-no-esta-instalada/218533#218533)  y funciono perfecto en un smartphone con android 7, pero en una **tablet con android 5.0** no funciona.
Por favor su ayuda o recomendaciones. Mil gracias.  **Código para detectar si la aplicación se encuentra instalada en el dispositivo a partir de su packagename, sería.**

```
public static boolean instaladaAplicacion(String packagename, Context context) {
    boolean response = false;
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        response = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i("Android", "NNFE aplicación no instalada: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}
```

**Si no encuentra la aplicación, abre el play store:**

```
String packageName = "com.example.speedometer";
    String MARKET_SQUEME = "market://details?id=";

    //Verifica si la aplicación se encuentra instalada.
    if(instaladaAplicacion(packageName, getApplicationContext())){
        Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);            
        //Abre aplicación.
        startActivity(i); 
    }else{ //No se encuentra instalada.
        //Abre aplicación en  Playstore
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(MARKET_SQUEME + packageName)));
    }
```

Comment: Me parece que debería funcionar sin problema, has revisado el LogCat si se muestra algo relacionado a este problema?

Comment: Tienes razón el código funciona sin problemas, encontré el error. Por alguna razón cuando intento abrir el Gboar (con package name "com.google.android.inputmethod.latin") con el código de abrir aplicación me muestra ese error. Por lo demás funciona perfecto. No entiendo porque no funciona. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que puede ser un error que se encuentra en los Gradle Scripts

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo build.gradle se definen las versiones mínimas y máximas del sdk

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entre mas alta sea tu version más features tendrás pero menos dispositivos podrán instalarla y viceversa. Revisa que version del sdk utiliza android 5.0 y ponla en el build.gradle